# How to set json respone as java object

Tags: java, json, spring

i have api and try to access link:

```
server/apps/ProcessRequest?req={"agent_id":"id","proccode":"380000","agent_pass":"pass","req_datetime":"20161108132741","customer_id":"547201743150","product_code":"001002","rrn":"uniquecode"}
```

and my problem is with the respone from link above, i want to set the respone as java object and use it.

i get this respone:

```
{
"resp_code": "0000",
"amount": "0",
"data": {
    "Status": "0000",
    "NomorPelanggan": "547",
    "IDPelanggan": "547",
    "Unsold": "[]",
    "Nama": "PLGN LPB., 05134710274",
    "TeleponUP": "123",
    "Daya": "2200",
    "KodeUP": "54720",
    "MaksimalKWH": "5000",
    "Tagihan": [
        {
            "Periode": "201611",
            "Total": 0
        }
    ],
    "NomorMeter": "05134710274",
    "Tarif": "R3",
    "TotalTagihan": "0",
    "ErrorMessage": "",
    "SessionId": "2016110813321820497",
    "Nominal": [
        20000,
        50000,
        100000,
        200000,
        500000,
        1000000,
        5000000,
        10000000,
        50000000
    ],
    "KodeDistribusi": "54"
},
"resp_desc": "Successful",
"proccode": "380000"}
```

how to set this respons as java object?

the api is not own by me, i dont now pojo's model of that api.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is serialisation. If you know the format of the Json you'll be receiving beforehand, you can simply use Gson to parse the Json and create a Java object out of it.

Suppose you have this json:

```
{
    "type": "Fiat",
    "model": "500",
    "colour": "white"
}
```

Try something like this:

```
public class Car {
    private String type;
    private String model;
    private String colour;
    // Getters and setters.
}

public static void main(final String... args) {
    String json = getTheJsonSomehow();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Car car = gson.fromJson(json, Car.class);
}
```

See [the documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2)

Answer (score 0):

if u not sure what the entire strutcture of de repsonse json.

u can simply turn the response string as a Map (based on u know the root node is a json object, rather than json array)

Through fastjson api like this:

```
Map<String, Object> list = JSON.parseObject("...", new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

the '...' is the resposne string

Answer (score 0):

Gson, json-simple, jackson are few of the libraries you could use. But with any of these you would have to define a Java class structure to represent the Json yourself for the un-marshalling.